# error on manifest file in the project

Tags: android

I had error on the manifest file when I tried to solve the GCM issue :

> error
>
> error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'label' with value '@string/title_activity_main').

The error appears here:

```
android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
```

**Manifest:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.elarabygroup"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.elarabygroup.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.elarabygroup.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- GCM connects to Google Services. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <service
            android:name="com.example.elarabygroup"
            android:enabled="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.example.elarabygroup.gcm2" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: So does the string exist in your resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please add `@string/title_activity_main` to your string resources.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the string in the `res/values/strings.xml` as an item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="title_activity_main">My Main Activity</string>   

</resources>
```